# Unable to use glyphicon images net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to migrate .NET MVC web app to .net core
I did put my assets in the wwwRoot folder as such:

[image]

Now the content folder includes the bootstrap. I am able to load the bootstrap.css but it is not finding the images

[image]

Here is the difinition of font-face:
[image]

here is my startup.cs

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

```
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
```

I loaded the css in my view
< link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
I used it in my view
< span id="brand-icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog">

Comment: @Calculuswhiz  <span id="brand-icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>                    if I put the code below, the images will load<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Try this:`../content/fonts/...`.

Comment: @Rena i tried this with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around it ../../fonts seems I need it to the wwwroot level

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

use complete url in @font-face such as below :

```
@font-face {
   font-family : 'G....';
   src : url('/content/fonts/.....');
....
}
```

Comment: You can use both Font Awesome and Github Octicons as a free alternative for Glyphicons.

Bootstrap 4 also switched from Less to Sass, so you might integerate the font's Sass (SCSS) into you build process, to create a single CSS file for your projects.

Comment: This works in .net and would like to use the same approach with .netcore